# Find Median in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, median

I'm having a little issue with finding a median out a range. Unfortunately I cannot use the built in function `Median` since there is not a set up range, but the variable are stored in a Dictionary. I found the following function online, which should return the median, but when I utilize I am getting a type mismatch "Array or User defined type expected". Here is the Function:

```
Private Function Median(x() As Double, n As Integer) As Double
'this function calculates the median of a vector

    'Determine Median
    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Median = 0.5 * (x(n / 2) + x((n + 2) / 2))
    Else
        Median = x((n + 1) / 2)
    End If

End Function
```

I'm trying to call the function in such a way:

```
x = Median(v_Array(), dct(vAdd).Count)
```

Where `V_array` is an Array where I'd like to store the values, to be copied over from the dictionary. I think the issue here relates to the part `x() as Double`. How can I insert an list of values if the value of `x` is a double? Would I need to use a loop to loop through the values in the array?

Ps. If you know any other function/way to get to the median out of a list of values in a dictionary, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use the worksheet function on an array though.

Comment: How is `v_Array` declared? (Given that you are going to pursuit the `v_Array` way, because like the previous comment suggests, you can call `Application.WorksheetFunction.Median` on an array.)

Comment: And you can generate an array from a dictionary in one line.

Comment: @QHarr how would you be able to do that? Thanks!

Comment: You just say dict.Keys or dict.Items and that generates an array. You usually then want to wrap that in an Application.Transpose

Comment: @GSerg The array is declared as variant at the moment. Should it be declared as double for the function to work?

Comment: @ChefTony It should be declared `As Double()`. But look into the built in function instead.